# KlarnaHybridSDK - Getting swamped with the message "Notifying Native Hook" [ANDROID]

Tags: android, kotlin, hybrid, klarna

**Problem description**

When debugging the web portion of my app either in chrome://inspect/#devices or directly in android studio I can see that I'm getting swamped with the message "Notifying Native Hook".
When using chrome://inspect/#devices to inspect the web page used in the app I see that the message has the source VM298:5 (quite sure that I've seen it with another number as well after VM). When clicking on the source I find the following function:

```
 (function () {
     if (document.readyState === "complete") {
         var foundMessageBridge = false
         function notifyMessageBridge() {
            console.log("Notifying Native Hook")
             if (window.__KlarnaNativeHook != null) {
                 console.log("Klarna Native Hook was notified")
                 window.__KlarnaNativeHook.setNativeReady()
                 foundMessageBridge = true
             } else {
                 window.setTimeout(notifyMessageBridge, 500)
             }
         }
         notifyMessageBridge()
     }
     window.addEventListener('load', () => {
         let interval = null
         let notifyMessageBridge = () => {
             if (window.__KlarnaNativeHook != null) {
                 window.__KlarnaNativeHook.setNativeReady()
                 clearInterval(interval)
             }
         }
         interval = setInterval(notifyMessageBridge, 500)
     })
 }())
```

Which finally led me to that it has something to do with Klarna. Since I'm getting swamped with this I suppose that my app is not getting into the if (window.__KlarnaNativeHook != null).

After some debugging I noticed the following:

- When I start the interaction with Klarna my app enters if (window.__KlarnaNativeHook != null). But only once and the spamming resumes afterwards.
- If I remove the line `(activity as MainActivity).klarnaHybridSDK.addWebView(myWebView)` the message swamping stops. Which I suppose is not that surprising.
- Apart from my app's web page empty untitled web pages are generated which only prints out "Notifying Native Hook" in the console and nothing else, no code, nothing.
- Apart from the swamping the app is working fine with Klarna.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the SDK or an error of mine.

Any suggestions on how to stop the spamming "Notifying Native Hook"? 
(I know how to filter it, but 120 messages/min * (my app's webpage + the untitleds generated) and doing it every time is getting tiresome)

**Code**

***MainActivity***

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KlarnaHybridSDKCallback {
...
    lateinit var klarnaHybridSDK : KlarnaHybridSDK
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        klarnaHybridSDK = KlarnaHybridSDK("myapp://", this)
        ...
    }
    override fun didHideFullscreenContent(webView: WebView, completion: OnCompletion) {
        Timber.i("Klarna didHideFullscreenContent called")
        completion.run()
    }

    override fun didShowFullscreenContent(webView: WebView, completion: OnCompletion) {
        Timber.i("Klarna didShowFullscreenContent called")
        completion.run()
    }

    override fun onErrorOccurred(webView: WebView, error: KlarnaMobileSDKError) {
        Timber.i("Klarna onErrorOccurred called")
        Timber.i("Klarna Error: $error")
    }

    override fun willHideFullscreenContent(webView: WebView, completion: OnCompletion) {
        Timber.i("Klarna willHideFullscreenContent called")
        completion.run()
    }

    override fun willShowFullscreenContent(webView: WebView, completion: OnCompletion) {
        Timber.i("Klarna willShowFullscreenContent called")
        completion.run()
    }
}
```

***Fragment Class***

```
class myFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        /*WEBVIEW*/
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        val context = this.activity?.applicationContext
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(
            WebAppInterface(
                myWebView, context
            ), "Android")
        myWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myWebView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            myWebView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
            if(this.activity?.applicationInfo?.flags != 0 && ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE != 0) {
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
                Timber.i("setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled")
            }
        }
        ticketWebView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient(){
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                ...
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                ...
                if (view != null) {
                    (activity as MainActivity).klarnaHybridSDK.newPageLoad(view)
                }
                ...
            }

            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onReceivedHttpError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?) {
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse)
                ...
                    //Added to prevent Klarna's address search failing to cause the app to show the error screen.
                    if (request?.url.toString().contains("klarna.com/eu/address")) {
                        Timber.i("${receivedError}")
                        Timber.i("Ignoring error since it's simply Klarna's address search failing")
                    }
                ...
            }
            @TargetApi(21)
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                val url = request?.url
                ...
                return (activity as MainActivity).klarnaHybridSDK.shouldFollowNavigation(url.toString())
            }

            /*To handle cases where the target API < 21*/
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                return (activity as MainActivity).klarnaHybridSDK.shouldFollowNavigation(url.toString())
            }
        }
        val url = "myAppUrl.php"
        val postData = "data=" + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8").toString()
        myWebView.postUrl(url, postData.toByteArray())
         return root
    }
    ...
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Started the app
2. Opened chrome://inspect/#devices in Chrome.
3. Located the relevant web page
4. Pressed "Inspect"

**Expected behavior**

Not getting swamped with the message in my console.

**Device and version:**

- Device: Samsung A10
- OS version: Android 9
- Klarna In-App SDK version: com.klarna.mobile:sdk:2.0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for reporting this issue. Fortunately, this problem will be fixed with a future release.

To give you more insight, this currently is an issue when the SDK tries to notify Klarna components in a WebView with no content; thus resulting in a page called ‘untitled’ with excessive number of logs.

Temporarily, this can be avoided by adding the WebView to the Hybrid SDK when a page is loaded.

Edit: @Myalakin We would like to inform you that this issue has been fixed by the latest releases of our SDK.